# How to make the header array bold when sending e-mail in google script?

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function sendEmail() 
{       
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    var fRes1 = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
    var email = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
    var headers = fRes1.getRange(1,1,1,fRes1.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
    var Row = fRes1.getRange(fRes1.getLastRow(),1,1,fRes1.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var message = "";
    var subject = "test";

    for(var i in Row) 
    {
        message += headers[i] + ': '+ Row[i] + "\n\n";     
    }

    // Send the email
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);  
}
```

This works and sends email just ok, but I need that "header[i]" be shown as bold. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add HTML body to your email,

```
function sendEmail() 
{       
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    var fRes1 = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
    var email = "xxxxx@gmail.com";
    var headers = fRes1.getRange(1,1,1,fRes1.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
    var Row = fRes1.getRange(fRes1.getLastRow(),1,1,fRes1.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var message = "";
    var subject = "test";

    for(var i in Row) 
    {
       //<br/> and <b> tags
        message += '<b>'+headers[i] +'</b>: '+ Row[i] + "<br/><br/>";     
    }

    // Send the email
    //MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);  
    MailApp.sendEmail({to: email, subject: subject, htmlBody: message,});
}
```

Read further [**HTML email template**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial) for apps script.